# Как отключить автовоспроизведение в Selenium chromedriver?

Tags: java, selenium

Использую `chromedriver` для тестирования, и необходимо отключить автовоспроизведение всех видео. Какие есть варианты это решить?

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setCapability("--autoplay-policy", "Document user activation is required.");
```

Не помогает хотя ручная установка параметра `chrome://flags/#autoplay-policy` решает эту проблему
. Однако она требует перезапуска браузера, что обессмысливает этот вариант.

Comment: каких видео? где смотрите?

Comment: @Senior Pomidor на тестируемом вэб-сервисе он пока в закрытом контуре, на некоторых страницах есть `autoplay` видео которые тормозят работу тестов.

Comment: autoplay - это фича видеоплеера, а не селениума

Comment: @Senior Pomidor Да, а видеоплеер в свою очередь часть страницы для управления элементами которой selenium и предназначен. Нет?

Comment: можно уточнить что за видио? пример кода со страницы и как они воспроизводятся (html, может средствами js стартуют или flash) и может как раз в это проблема?

Comment: @users к сожалению инспекция кода почти ничего не показывает, просто `<div id="content-separator" tabindex="0" class="style-scope watch"></div>` и все(. Из-за этого я и отказался от идеи взаимодействовать с плеером так как не с чем по сути. Вот и пытаюсь на браузер надавить чтобы видео отключить. Частично удалось через `options.addArguments("--autoplay-policy=document-user-activation-required");` но не всегда работает при некоторых переходах все рано заускается. В идеале вообще запретить браузеру видео проигрывать, при любых комбинациях.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в настройках хрома можно отключить эту функцию, но не уверен, что поможет, если открыть через chromedriver. откройте страницу `chrome://flags/#autoplay-policy` и измените настроки на "Document user activation is required".

Можно попробовать настроить капасити с помошю аргумента `--autoplay-policy`

Comment: так пробовал не помогает `options.setCapability("--autoplay-policy", false);`.

Comment: попробуй `Document user activation is required`

Comment: `options.setCapability("--autoplay-policy", "Document user activation is required.")` к сожалению не помогает.

Answer (score 0):

- Дополнение Disable HTML5 Autoplay и запуск с аргументом --load-extension=chrome-extension
- Попробуйте запустить с аргументом --headless  (там вроде как autoplay игнорит)